# Multiplying RSA Cipher generated by 'phpseclib' with a Number

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, biginteger, phpseclib

I am implementing an algorithm using php. Also for RSA encryption of text, phpseclib's RSA implementation is being used. I am successfully able to encrypt / decrypt the values. One part of algorithm requires me to multiply a nonce (random number generated) with the cipher generated by RSA.

For example: (Explaining from algorithm's perspective, so taking simple numbers)

If p=3 & q=7, then n=21, Phi(n) = 12, e = 5, d = 5.

Also if message is 12 (some string, I am taking integer to explain requirement clearly), then cipher is given by 12^5(mod 21) = 3.

Let nonce generated be 6, in this case I shall get 3 * 6 = 18. This result again will be used in further  calculations which in later case will be decrypted. (Equations are mathematically proven correct, not giving details of algorithm because of privacy & copyright issue)

Mathematically all this works well, but I chose phpseclib's RSA implementation. This is first time I am using the library functions. I did go through the documentation of phpseclib, but couldn't find a way to do it. (There will be way I am sure, may be I am out of patience to identify it).

It would of great help, if someone finds me a workaround for this issue. (I am also ready for changing library in implementation i.e. anything else apart from phpseclib which can provide this functionality). I just hope there is way for it, or should I implement my own RSA methods ?

(Version of phpseclib is 0.3.6)

Comment: phpseclib comes with a file Math/BigInteger.php on careful observation, I found that RSA Crypt method returns answer in binary. We can use bin2hex method to convert it to hexadecimal cipher, this can be passed to Math_BigInteger(hex_cipher,16) to get BigInteger object.

The class BigInteger provides method multiply which works like charm for us. So no need to panic for it. If we go through examples for Math_BigInteger in phpseclib, we will understand how to use the methods.

I thank to those who are bothering about this issue, I found out myself.

Comment: Are you trying to do RSA blinding or something?

Comment: No @neubert It's a new Scheme being proposed, I am trying to implement which as a part of it uses RSA for signing of parameters & to create a hashed text. (Took my time in going through implementation of phpseclib). Anyway I got the answer! Couldn't answer myself because of less reputation, my previous comment has answer.